# How to give a parent name in serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three serializers as below:

```
class MalbSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = malb
        fields = ('zoning', 'zoningdesc', )

class MasrSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = masr
        fields = ('solddate', 'soldprice', )

class MataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = mata
        fields = ('assessyear', 'landvalue', )
```

The views is as below:

```
    malb_serializer = MalbSerializer(malb.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)
    masr_serializer = MasrSerializer(masr.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)
    mata_serializer = MataSerializer(mata.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)

    reponse = malb_serializer.data + masr_serializer.data + mata_serializer.data

    return Response(reponse)
```

as a result, the response is as below:

```
[
    {
        "zoning": null,
        "zoningdesc": null,
    },
    {
        "solddate": null,
        "soldprice": null,
    },
    {
        "assessyear": null,
        "landvalue": null,
    }
]
```

I want to give each element a tag like as below:

```
[
    {"Land Building": {
        "zoning": null,
        "zoningdesc": null,
    }},
    { "Sales Record":{
        "solddate": null,
        "soldprice": null,
    }},
     {"Tax Assessment":{
        "assessyear": null,
        "landvalue": null,
    }}
]
```

I have tried to use a nested serializer, but I don't have a model which includes all these three messages, which can I use to give them a json parent name base on my current code?

Any help will be many appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can define serializer like this:

```
AnotherSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    malb = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    masr = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    mata = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('malb', 'masr', 'mamta',)

    def get_malb(self):
        return MalbSerializer(malb.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)

    def get_masr(self):
        return MasrSerializer(masr.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)

    def get_mata(self):
        return MataSerializer(mata.objects.filter(maid=maid), many=True)
```